# Why my dynamical programming of fibonacci doesn't give a linear time?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am watching this [video](https://youtu.be/W2ote4jCuYw?t=8m). Basically it says that using a `dictionary`(python's language?) will make calculate fibonacci from time O(n^2) to O(n).

I have the programmed the following code, `fibo1` ought to be O(n) but actually it runs really slow. `fibo2` is the normal recursion and it is O(n^2) solution, but actually it runs much faster than `fibo1`. How can I understand this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
int fibo1(int i, std::map<int,int>& m);
int fibo2(int i);

int main()
{
    std::map<int,int> m;
    m[1] = 1; m[2] = 1;
    int n = 40;
    std::cout << fibo1(n,m);
    //std::cout << fibo2(n);
    return 0;
}

int fibo1(int i, std::map<int,int>& m)   {
    if(m[i]==0)   {
        return fibo1(i-1,m)+fibo1(i-2,m);
    }
    return m[i];
}

int fibo2(int i) {
    if(i==1 || i==2) {
        return 1;
    }

    return fibo2(i-1)+fibo2(i-2);
}
```

Comment: Why no comment vote down?

Comment: Most probably that `dictionary` you talk about provides O(1) insert/lookup behavior. `std::map` has O(log(n)) insert/lookup as far as I know. You can use `unordered_map` for O(1) behavior though. And also, you need to assign `m[i]` before returning inside the `if` statement.

Comment: @buzhidao Profile your code to find the bottlenecks. _"Why no comment vote down?"_ It probably means you should improve your question. Generally there's no comment needed with every downvote.

Comment: @zahir unordered_map is then just like `dictionary` structure in python--a hash table?

Comment: So, bug aside, the purpose of `m` is to cache values that have already been calculated? And those values will be for arguments from 1 up to n. That sounds very much like an array or a vector. A map has far more overhead for no benefit here.

Comment: @PeteBecker What about unordered_map as mentioned above?

Comment: A map (of either flavor) is designed for lookups with sparse keys. Here, the keys are 0, 1, 2, ..., n with no gaps. The simplest way to look up those keys is to treat them as indices into an array, if you can come up with a reasonable upper bound at compile time, or a vector if you can't. A map allocates a separate block for each entry; that's far more overhead than an array or a vector. And lookups are more complicated for a map. It's just not the appropriate data structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never actually write the `fib[n]` at `m[n]`, so you never look up anything and always recalculate it. Use `m[i] = fibo1(i-1,m) + fibo1(i-2,m);` in the if statement rather than the return line.

Comment: Haha nice catch. I hate these kind of bugs. It's like your mind fills in the code you've written with the code that's in your head and you miss it. You've got to actually execute the code in your head line by line instead of 'reading' it.

Answer (score 3):

In the fibo1 method you are only returning the values without setting the map a proper value.

```
int fibo1(int i, std::map<int,int>& m)   {
if(m[i]==0)   {
    m[i] = fibo1(i-1,m)+fibo1(i-2,m);
}
return m[i];
}
```

Also, you should consider using a simple vector instead of a map to get a better performance

Answer (score 1):

You do not store result in the map, and you should remember, that `std::map::operator[]` is doing lookup which is significantly expensive, so you should avoid multiple lookups for the same key:

```
int fibo1(int i, std::map<int,int>& m)   {
    int &value = m[i];
    if( value == 0)   {
        value = fibo1(i-1,m)+fibo1(i-2,m);
    }
    return value;
}
```